# Google Jobs URL using Wildcard Subdomains

Tags: json, wildcard-subdomain

I have successfully added JSON code to my job listings so they now appear on Google Jobs.

The problem is many of the URLs for the jobs have incorrect wildcard subdomains such as:

https://mail.mywebsite.com
https://ww.mywebsite.com

Wildcards/subdomains are not covered by my SSL certificate, so when you click these links a warning page appears to say that the website has been improperly configured and to proceed with caution.

It seems to be picking these wildcard URLs up from Google search results instead of taking the URL of the actual page. I have added the 'URL' property to the code but it seems to ignore it.

Is there another property I can add to the JSON code to get Google to use the proper URL?

Comment: I can answer your question but for that, I need to look at your website URL. I would be better if you provide me the URL.

A wildcard SSL can only secure level-1 sub-domains, If I can see the SSL information I can give you the perfect solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My current SSL is not for Wildcards so I am not expecting it to work with these subdomains. I need to know how to get Google to take the correct URL starting with: https://www